# Rake tasks on Rails 3.1.3 - Application already initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm unable to get rake precompile tasks running with Rails 3.1.3. I get the following error:

```
$ rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/tristankromer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/tristankromer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@toomanyninjas/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
rake aborted!
Application has been already initialized.
/Users/tristankromer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@toomanyninjas/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:95:in `initialize!'
```

Same thing happens when I used `bundle exec` or when I deploy to heroku cedar stack.

Not quite sure where to start on this one. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I'm having issues with every rake task:

```
rake aborted!
Application has been already initialized.
/Users/tristankromer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249@joke-off/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:95:in `initialize!'
```

Comment: what happen if you launch "bundle exec rake assets:precompile" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading rake to 0.9.2.2 and using ruby 1.9.2-p290 seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, I didn't want to upgrade ruby, and what ended up working for me was the renaming config.ru in RAILS_ROOT to config.ru.bak

http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=109

I came across this after realizing I was having an issue getting Passenger to recognize the "RailsEnv" setting my my virtual hosts conf

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Rails 3.2.6

The reason it was happening had to do with a path linked gem having a bundle folder. in my gemfile

like so:

gem 'some-gem', :path => "vendor/some-gem"

In order to fix the issue I just moved the bundle folder out of the path linked gem.

mv vendor/some-gem/bundle ~

Once the bundle file was gone it worked perfectly